# SignalR don't call jQuery function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I've this piece of code in my page, but it don't run when i make changes in the database, what could be the problem.
This starts well, when i load the page this executes the function twice, but if i send a message to the database this doens't execute.

```
$(function () {

var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
chat.client.allTalks = function () {
    refresh();
};
$.connection.hub.start();
    refresh();

});
```

**SERVER SIDE (HUB):**

```
    [HubName("chatHub")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public static void AllTalks()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
            context.Clients.All.allTalks();
        }
    }
```

**HANDLER**

**...**

```
using (SqlCommand command = new 
SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[chat_talks]", connection)) {
```

//CONTENT

```
SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
```

**...**
    }

```
        public void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            ChatHub.AllTalks();
        }
```

**GLOBAL.ASAX**

```
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectSellerConnection"].ConnectionString);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: i think you need move $.connection.hub.start(); before you run chat.client.allTalks and you need var chat be a global variable

Comment: i've puted console.log in every step, and at the page load it starts, but when i update the database it don't call my jQuery function

Comment: Try [Enabling logging](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/ranw/2013/02/26/logging-with-signalr/) and check the [SignalR Troubleshooting](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting)

Comment: by logging i see no problems.

Comment: Have you debugged/traced your server-side code to verify that `Clients.allTasks` is actually being invoked. Can you add your server-side code to your question? I would also add your client-side logs to your question. Even if you see no problems in the client-side logs, it might be helpful to others trying to answer your question.

Comment: signalR is started, but if there are any changes, this doesn't call the responsible function "refresh()"

Comment: can you add the full code of dependency_OnChange? where do you call the hub client method (Clients.All.allTalks(), I assume)?

Comment: done, i've inserted the Gloaba.asax dependecy

Comment: @Severiano you didn't added the _dependency_OnChange_ code. Neither answered what halter73 asked to you.

Comment: as halter73 said, you need to add debugging info: 1) is ChatHub.AllTalks called when your DB changes? 2) is chat.client.allTalks called? 3) is refresh called? set a few breakpoints, enable logging on the client-side and then add that info to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, it is redundant to have your first line in your server-side code. There is no need to call for a hubContext inside the Hub. You can just do:

```
public static void AllTalks()
{
    Clients.All.allTalks();
}
```

I would suggest, perhaps foolishly, to not use SQL Dependency. I would instead suggest using the following technique of calling SignalR (specifically, it will call the client functions):

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.allTalks();
```

You can call this in, for example, actions in MVC and WebAPI Controllers, thus meaning if you've done any database updates in those actions, you can subsequently call clients using this methodology. I know it's not as fancy as SQL Dependency, and perhaps not the answer your looking for, but it will solve your problem - since it appears the problem seems to be with SignalR detecting the database changes.

In other words, this methodology will work, but it's probably not the precise one you are hoping for.